# How to create a chart to get number of account for a customer by period in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue we want to create a request to add customer number of account by period.

For each account I have : accountid, customerid, createddate and deleteddate

```
select accountid,customerid, createddate , deleteddate from account
where customerid = 1
```

This customer have 4 accounts :

```
accountid | customerid | createddate                | deleteddate 

2145      |  6641      | 2018-12-12 10:39:16.457    | 2020-03-26 00:00:12.540

2718      |  6641      | 2020-02-11 15:04:51.643    | 2020-03-26 00:00:04.947

2825      |  46818     | 2020-04-14 15:28:30.400    | 2020-04-29 15:58:30.651
  
2851      |  46818     | 2020-06-05 12:41:45.790    | NULL
```

so i want a chart for current year to get the nb of account of the customer not for each month but for each modification

For exemple 02/01/2020 I will have 1 account

03/01/2020 I will have 0 account

It is possible to do that or something like that in SQL ? And how can I do it if it's possible.

Comment: I don't understand the logic for the counts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff each month we have to count the number of active account

Comment: The count for Feb 2020 should be 1.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok thank you do you have any response to my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get the nb of account of the customer not for each month but for each modification

Is this what you want?

```
select 
    x.customer_id, 
    x.modifdate, 
    sum(x.cnt) over(partition by x.customer_id order by x.modifdate) no_active_accounts
from mytable t
cross apply (
    values (customer_id, createddate, 1), (customer_id, deleteddate, -1)
) as x(customer_id, modifdate, cnt)
where modifdate is not null
```

For each customer, this generates one record everytime an account is created or deleted, with the modification date and the running count of active accounts.

Comment: it doesn't work for me i have negative account of null acount but it shoudn't be null

Comment: @Soleyne: I added a condition to filter out rows with `null` dates.

Comment: Thank you for your help ^^. Do you have any reference to understand how it works.

Comment: Just a question how can I do if when I have multiple record for previous year I want to last one but for the current year i want all the record ?